# Import from CSV to Mysql round up digits

Tags: mysql, csv

I have a data in CSV file when i import into Mysql automatically sets the data type varchar and round up the digits forexample in CSV. if the value is `15.563` after the import it looks like `15.56`. what technique do i use to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't automatically do anything like that, it just conforms to whatever your schema is as its defined, and if that's `VARCHAR`, then so is the data that's imported.

If you need three places of precision you should probably be using a `DECIMAL(10,3)` or something similar depending on how many significant digits you want in total. `10,3` allows for `N,NNN,NNN.NNN`.

Comment: i am importing from .csv file, what do you mean by schema you mean mysql schema

Comment: You need to `LOAD DATA INFILE` into an existing table, so that's what I mean, the schema of the target table.